# How to find a Friday after last Wednesday of month?

Tags: icalendar, rrule

What iCal RRULE expression should I use to find a Friday after last Wednesday of month? So I need (RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=-1WE) + 2 days...

Comment: Someone might correct me on this, but I'm thinking this can't be expressed with `RRULE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Evert that this is not possible with a single RRULE.

You can, however, achieve that with a combination of multiple RRULEs.

That way you can split your event into multiple events each one having one of the RRULEs below:

If Wednesday falls on the last or second last day of a month, our Friday will be the 1st or 2nd of the next month

```
FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTHDAY=1,2;BYDAY=1FR
```

In months with 31 days the earliest date for the last Wednesday is the 25th, so the next Friday will be one of day 27-31:

```
FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTH=1,3,5,7,8,10,12;BYMONTHDAY=27,28,29,30,31;BYDAY=FR
```

In months with 30 days the earliest date for the last Wednesday is the 24th, so the next Friday will be one of day 26-30:

```
 FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTH=4,6,9,11;BYMONTHDAY=26,27,28,29,30;BYDAY=FR
```

February is a tricky one, because in non-leap years the the Friday we want will be between the 24th and 28th, but in leap years it's between the 25th and 29th. However, within the next 50 years there is only one leap year in which February 24th is a Friday, which is 2040 (check out the result of [FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTHDAY=24;BYMONTH=2;BYDAY=FR](http://recurrence-expansion-service.appspot.com/reaas?dtstart=20170224&rrule=FREQ%3DMONTHLY%3BBYMONTHDAY%3D24%3BBYMONTH%3D2%3BBYDAY%3DFR&skip=&max_instances=100&expansion_window_end=20661231T000000)), so the following RRULE will be correct until 2040:

```
FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTH=2;BYMONTHDAY=24,25,26,27,28,29;BYDAY=FR
```

If you're concerned about the leap years, add an EXDATE like below and you're good for the next 100 years (make these DATE-TIME values if your start date has a time):

```
EXDATE;VALUE=DATE:20400224,20680224,20960224,21080224
```

If you know for sure that your clients support multiple RRULEs (which has been deprecated halfheartedly in [RFC 5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#appendix-A.1) but still was perfectly valid in [RFC 2445](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2445#page-52)) you could add them into a single event as well, but I wouldn't recommend that.